# How can I merge my iTunes connect account and member center account to one Apple ID?

Tags: app-store-connect

I am enrolled for a iOS developer team in member center, using one Apple ID. Unfortunately, I was enrolled into iTunes connect using another Apple ID.

Is there anyway, I can update any one of the Apple ID to make it same? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: i have the same problem. it is a multi-way merge db pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve this by inviting my iTunes connect apple id to join in the developer Team. Then I configured the same in xcode preferences as well.

Later I removed the first apple id from Dev portal team.